# UIScrollView subviews and setNeedsDisplay

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, reload, setneedsdisplay

I've the following problem :

I have a UIView containing a UIScrollView as a subview. (nib file).
Programmatically I add several subviews (UIImageView) to the UIScrollView, each UIImageview contains an image loaded from the net asynchronously, so I need to update the scrollView when the images are downloaded. In the class responsible of the images fetching, I advertise the the View controller responsible to manage the scrollView, using this code

```
[[(MosaicViewController *)data] scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```

the Ivar data is a pointer to the ViewController.
This stuff don't work,no reload of the scrollView happen
To be sure that the call is triggered I wrote a method inside the viewController containing the scrollView, and inside this method I called setNeedsDisplay,

```
[(MosaicViewController *)data updateView];

-(void) updateView
{
    NSLog(@"setNeedsDisplay");
    [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

the method updateView is triggered correctly, I mean is called after each Image is downloaded, but the scrollView contents isn't updated. In the ViewController containing the scrollView I don't implement the drawRect method, could be this the reason for the lack of update after calling setNeedsDisplay?

Any help/suggestion/reference etc.. is welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -4):

Dude are you doing imageView.image = downloadedImage ??

Also you should not have to do [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay] since you did not change anything on scrollView !!

What changed is the content of the imageView and imageView.image = downloadedImage will automatically trigger setNeedsDisplay on imageView !!

Some other check points

Is scrollView visible?
Is scrollView.contentSize set??
Is the scrollView frame correct ??